# Retrieving MXD Display view page units with ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy

I've read some articles about translating map units into page units for getting distances in an MXD.  I have not seen a post about how to get the page units programmatically from ArcPy.  *Is it possible to in any version of ArcMap 10.x to get the page units programmatically?*  DisplayUnits and mapUnits from dataframe do not suffice.

Edit:
 [This post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/21514/convert-point-xy-to-page-units-xy-using-arcpy)   only answers how to translate units between map and page units.  It does not answer how to retrieve with arcpy page units (cm, in, etc.).
I am not looking for the answer to how to translate units from map distance to page distance and back.  I am simply asking about how to retrieve page units.

Comment: I don't think what you are requesting is possible. The same MXD applies to multiple "pages", so choosing one value would be wrong. Besides, distances are a property of the CRS (coordinate reference system)

Comment: What articles have you read about this?  I think it can be done if you base the link on one data frame even if there are many and that there is already a Q&A here about it.

Answer (score 1):

This is not available in 10.x using arcpy. It can only be set within ArcGIS Desktop application and not using arcpy.

The [documentation](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-mapping/dataframe-class.htm) states:

> Page units can only be changed in the ArcMap via Customize > ArcMap
> Options > Layout View Tab

However, they have added the read/write property [pageUnits](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/mapping/layout-class.htm) in arcpy for ArcGIS Pro.

The documentation explains:

> A layout's page units. Below is a list of valid strings when setting
> the page units.
>
> - CENTIMETER —Centimeter
> - INCH —Inch
> - MILLIMETER —Millimeter
> - POINT —Point

There is likely a way to access the information you need using ArcObjects. You can access ArcObjects using python. Have a look at [Accessing ArcObjects from Python](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/80/accessing-arcobjects-from-python) for instructions.

Comment: I have read this: Page units can only be changed in the ArcMap via Customize > ArcMap Options > Layout View Tab.  This documentation note is vague since it is only saying it can be changed but not reference as to whether it can just be access.  I guess to achieve this, I either need to jump to ArcGIS Pro or write custom code in ArcObjects.  Thanks for your response.

Comment: If this answer helps you, please accept it.